# LibGit2Sharp Pull() not pulling deleted files

Tags: c#, git, winforms, github, libgit2

I made a program to pull from a public repository hosted on my github.Cloning a project works just fine (the way I do it anyway), but I've been trying to get it to work to pull everything and once you delete a file it doesn't pull that file anymore. In my case I deleted the .gitignore from the pulled repository (the cloned one basically) and now the `repo.Network.Pull()` doesn't want to re-download it from the repo. Same goes with any other file I delete.

```
        private void PullButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(BrowseText.Text))
                if (Directory.Exists(BrowseText.Text))
                {
                    AddToDebugBox("Starting Pull request to \"" + BrowseText.Text + "\"...");

                    if (!Repository.IsValid(BrowseText.Text))
                    {
                        AddToDebugBox("No Git init found at: \"" + BrowseText.Text + "\"...");
                        Repository.Clone("https://github.com/sxbrentxs/FPS-GLU.git", BrowseText.Text);
                        AddToDebugBox("Created new git init at: \"" + BrowseText.Text + "\".");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        AddToDebugBox("Found git init at: \"" + BrowseText.Text + "\".");

                        using (Repository repo = new Repository(BrowseText.Text))
                        {
                            AddToDebugBox("Starting pull request...");
                            PullOptions options = new PullOptions();
                            options.FetchOptions = new FetchOptions();

                            repo.Network.Pull(new Signature("Updater", "Updater@RoZoShoGitUpdater.nl", new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now)), options);

                            AddToDebugBox("Completed pull request.");
                            AddToDebugBox("Calculating differences...");

                            TreeChanges changes = repo.Diff.Compare<TreeChanges>();

                            AddToDebugBox(string.Format("{0} files changed.", changes.Count()));

                            foreach (TreeEntryChanges c in changes)
                                AddToDebugBox(string.Format("Path: {0} | Change made: {1}", c.Path, c.Status));
                        }

                        AddToDebugBox("Operations completed.");
                        cleanready = !cleanready;
                    }
                }
                else
                    AddToDebugBox("Cannot pull to non-existing path: \"" + BrowseText.Text + "\"...");
            else
                AddToDebugBox("Cannot pull to nothing: \"" + BrowseText.Text + "\"...");
        }
```

This is the log I have at the end of pressing my pull button:

```
23:41:55 > Folder: "E:\Projects\Test" selected.
23:41:58 > Starting Pull request to "E:\Projects\Test"...
23:41:58 > Found git init at: "E:\Projects\Test".
23:41:58 > Starting pull request...
23:41:59 > Completed pull request.
23:41:59 > Calculating differences...
23:41:59 > 1 files changed.
23:41:59 > Path: .gitignore | Change made: Deleted
23:41:59 > Operations completed.
```

What am I forgetting or doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to do a forced checkout just as you would from the cmd-line with `git`:

Example of a forced checkout to the head of the "master" branch:

```
head = repo.Branches.Single (branch => branch.FriendlyName == "master");
var checkoutOptions = new CheckoutOptions ();
checkoutOptions.CheckoutModifiers = CheckoutModifiers.Force;
repo.Checkout (head, checkoutOptions);
```

Comment: That fixed it. Thank you very much. do want to note, though, that I did not have a `branch.FriendlyName` in my project. But changing it to `branch.Name` seemed to do the trick.

Comment: @sxbrentxs FYI: You might using an older version, `FriendlyName` replaced the obsolete Name prop. https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/pull/1020